# Excel VBA - search for a word in a text file and return true or false in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have about 200 text files with different names that gets stored in a folder. What I want is when a specific word is found (ex error, fault). I want excel to mention `true` or `false` next the text file name which is in column A.

```
Name        Error Found
Textfile1   TRUE
Textfile2   FALSE
Textfile3   TRUE
Textfile4   TRUE
Textfile5   TRUE
Textfile6   TRUE
Textfile7   TRUE
Textfile8   TRUE
Textfile9   TRUE
Textfile10  FALSE
Textfile11  FALSE
Textfile12  FALSE
Textfile13  FALSE
Textfile14  FALSE
```

Comment: What's the *exact* problem you're having with doing this?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Reading [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) will help you get an answer sooner. Remember, this isn't a code-writing service, so post what you've got & we can help you fix it. If you don't know where to start, try using the Macro Recorder.

Answer (score 1):

I was bored, this code is untested and far from perfect. Paste it into a new code module and adjust the constants to suit your needs.

This might not work at all, but might give you some pointers.

```
Public Const SearchPath = "C:\example\"
Public Const SearchTerm = "helloworld"

Sub Main()
Dim oFSO As Object: Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim oFolder As Object
Dim oFile As Object

Dim Sheet As Worksheet: Set Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim Index As Integer: Index = 1
Dim Result As Boolean
Dim Search As String: Search = SearchTerm
' retreive a list of files
    Set oFolder = oFSO.getFolder(SearchPath)

    For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
        Sheet.Cells(Index, 1).Value2 = oFile.Name
        Index = Index + 1
    Next oFile

    Set oFile = Nothing
    Set oFolder = Nothing
    Set oFSO = Nothing

' process list of files
    Index = 1

    While Not Sheet.Cells(Index, 1).Value2 = ""
        Result = Process(SearchPath & Sheet.Cells(Index, 1), Search) ' only the filename was being passed, added the parent folder from the constant above
        If Result = True Then
            Sheet.Cells(Index, 2).Value2 = "TRUE"
        Else
            Sheet.Cells(Index, 2).Value2 = "FALSE"
        End If
        Index = Index + 1
    Wend
End Sub

Public Function Process(ByVal File As String, ByVal Search As String) As Boolean
Dim Result As Boolean: Result = False
Dim FileNumber As Integer: FileNumber = FreeFile()
Dim Data As String

    Open File For Input As #FileNumber
    While Not EOF(FileNumber)
        Line Input #FileNumber, Data
        If InStr(1, Search, Data) > 0 Then
            Result = True
            GoTo BOut
        End If
    Wend
BOut: ' I used the wrong syntax for goto statements here
    Close #FileNumber
    Process = Result

End Function
```

Comment: it returns an error :(
unable to pass through function

Comment: @AslamRasheed - there were a few minor errors in the code which I've fixed now.

Comment: Hi NickSlash
you have solved part of my problem. Amazing.. I am able to list all the files into excel.. I mean all the name of the files appear...  
however there is still an error at this line
"Open File For Input As #FileNumber" it takes value as 1 and then nothing happens...

Comment: The code works without issue for me. Please ensure that the `SearchPath` constant at the top of my example ends with a slash. That is the only thing I can think might be causing the problem.